# How to read multiple string using fgets()

Tags: fgets

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;
struct addr           
 char name[30];    
char street[30];  
long int ph_num;   
};
int main()
{

 addr person[2];
 int a;
 for(int n=0;n<2;n++)
 {
  puts("Enter name of person");
  fgets(person[n].name,30,stdin);
  a=(strlen(person[n].name)-1);
   if(person[n].name[a]=='\n')
 {
     person[n].name[a]='\0';
 }
  puts(person[n].name);
  puts("Enter street of person");
  fgets(person[n].street,30,stdin);
 a=(strlen(person[n].street)-1);
 if(person[n].street[a]=='\n')
 {
     person[n].street[a]='\0';
 }
  puts(person[n].street);
  puts("Enter ph of person");
  scanf("%ld",&person[n].ph_num);
  printf("%ld",person[n].ph_num);

 }

return 0;
}
```

This piece of code is working fine for only the first time but after the first, in the second iteration I am not able to write the person name(skipping direct to the person[n].name).I am not able not to get what may be the problem here although I guess it may be related to how the fgets function works.

Please don't -ve vote , this may seem trivial but its a problem I am facing and too many of -ve votes will debarred me from asking further questions.
You can comment and I will heed to delete the question if this question is really that redundant or naive or trivial but don't -ve vote.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Either use `fgets()` to read everything, or use `cin >> ...` t read everything.    Don't mix them.    While it is possible to mix them, there are numerous gotchas - such as what you are seeing - in doing so.

For example, ...

- Do all of your input in a consistent way.   If using `fgets()` to read something, use `fgets()` to read everything, and don't use C++ stream extraction (operator `>>`, etc) on the same stream.    The reason is that they handle things like newlines differently - for example, the stream extraction may leave a newline pending, and a subsequent call of `fgets()` will encounter it straight away, and return immediately (and without reading data, as you are seeing).
- Although there is a relationship and synchronisation between C's
  `stdin` and C++ `std::cin`, it is a good idea to use one or the
  other and not mix them, because they each buffer data differently - and, depending on how the system manages streams, or on how other functions in
  your program set properties of `stdin` or `std::cin` or their
  buffers, there can be similar unexpected interactions between them.

Comment: after using the c style i/p, the problem remain persistent.I am still not able to  write the person names second time of the iteration.

Comment: So change your code and avoid using `cin >> ...` immediately after use of `fgets(...., stdin)`.  For example, do all reading from `stdin` using `fgets()`, and interpret the data as needed (as a name, a street, a number).    Also keep in mind that reading from `stdin` does not necessarily flusg `std::cout`.

Comment: i have to use fflush(stdin); to flush the stdin stream to execute the program as intended.

Comment: Only if you don't understand my advice, or don't bother to take it.   `fflush(stdin)` gives undefined behaviour anyway - it is just happenstance if it happens to clear pending input.

Comment: I have updated the question,please check it.Though the problem remains the same,on second iteration may be due to scanf() which cannot get past '/n' in the stdin buffer I having a new line as input to the fgets() and getting a new line for the same.Please suggest some way, while flushing stdin works fine that is clearing the input buffer.But I recently come to know that it springs unwanted behaviours.

Comment: You're still mixing use of `fgets(..., stdin)` with usage of `scanf()` - which does formatted reading from `stdin`.   Hence you still have the unwanted interaction between them (one leaves data in `stdin`'s buffer that makes the other behave in unwanted ways) as they handle newlines differently.   Be consistent with that (e.g. interact directly with `stdin` only using `fgets()`, and parse strings using `sscanf()` [note the double `s` in that name] if needed), and you won't need to worry about flushing `stdin` in any way.

Comment: How to read the long integer "long int ph_num" then because fgets(....stdin) is for strings reading,right. I have little knowledge about parsing or how it works.Can you explain it or give me the link?Or can you suggest anything but using fgets() in this case.

Comment: Look up the standard `sscanf()` function.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is missing the declaration of the `struct addr` but I suppose that is just a type (it would not compile).

This behaviour is caused probably by the mixed usage of `fgets` and stream input reader `cin`. You should use only one of them in your program as their behaviour is quite different. Try to replace `cin >> person[n].ph_num;` with

```
 fgets(person[n].ph_num, 30, stdin);
```

Comment: I am taking down the question,despite humble request guys have -ve voted it.